# Efficiently Animating pcolormesh

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

Im trying to save a GIF with the evolucion of some waves in 2d using pcolormesh (using surface or wireframe would also be ok).

This has been my aproach so far:
set the quadmesh to plot in polar coordinates:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation as FuncAnimation
pi=np.pi


rmax=6.
r=2*np.linspace(0,np.sqrt(rmax*.5),100)**2  
phi=np.linspace(0,2*pi,80)

R, P = np.meshgrid(r, phi)
X, Y = R*np.cos(P), R*np.sin(P)
```

set the figure and functions for the animation:
count is the amount of frames i have.
Z is a count*2D-array with the values i want to plot. 
(it has the sum of some fourier like series)

```
fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()
def anim_I(count,r,phi):
    anim=np.zeros((count,len(phi), len(r)))
    for i in range(count):
        anim[i,:,:]=coef_transf(final_coefs[i,:,:,:,0],r,phi)**2
    return anim

Z=anim_I(count,r,phi)
def animate(i):
    pyplot.title('Time: %s'%time[i])
    #This is where new data is inserted into the plot.
    plot=ax.pcolormesh(X, Y,Z[i,:,:],cmap=pyplot.get_cmap('viridis'),vmin=0., vmax=15.)
    return plot,

ax.pcolormesh(X, Y,Z[0,:,:],cmap=pyplot.get_cmap('viridis'),vmin=0., vmax=15.)
pyplot.colorbar()

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate,  frames = range(0,count,7), blit = False)
```

i don't really need to see it live, so i just save a gif.

```
anim.save('%d_%d_%d-%d.%d.%d-2dgif.gif' %(localtime()[0:6]), writer='imagemagick')     
pyplot.close()
```

While this works, it can take to an hour to make the gif of a even a hundred frames.

I wan't to know what would be the correct way to do this so it could be usable.

I have seen the other post in this regard, but i couldn't get the code working, or it would be just as inneficient.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to write

```
def animate(i):
pyplot.title('Time: %s'%time[i])
#This is where new data is inserted into the plot.
plot=plot.set_array(Z[i,:,:].ravel())
return plot,
```

instead of

```
def animate(i):
pyplot.title('Time: %s'%time[i])
#This is where new data is inserted into the plot.
plot=ax.pcolormesh(X, Y,Z[i,:,:],cmap=pyplot.get_cmap('viridis'),vmin=0., vmax=15.)
return plot,
```

This does not create a new object every time you call the animate funtion. Instead it changes the image of object that was already created.
However, the set_array method seems to need a flattened array, hence the .ravel().

This only produces the right image if you set the shading option of the pcolormap function to shading='gouraud'.
I don't know why, unfortunatelly, it seems to have to do with the sorting of the array.

I hoped, that helped a little.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest inserting a

```
pyplot.clf()
```

at the beginning of your `animate(i)` function. This will start each frame with a blank figure. Otherwise, I suspect the plot will not be cleared, and the long time is due to actually plotting all previous frame below the new one.